# Predictions on transformed series post intervention analysis

Tags: forecasting, arima, data-transformation, prediction-interval, intervention-analysis

I have taken this logged data and performed an intervention analysis:

```
         Jan       Feb       Mar       Apr       May       Jun       Jul       Aug       Sep       Oct
1  0.8837675 0.7608058 0.8241754 0.9162907 0.8919980 1.0006319 0.9969486 1.0079579 0.9360934 0.9122827
2  0.8544153 0.5988365 0.8754687 0.9001613 0.8671005 1.0402767 0.9858168 1.0331845 0.9321641 0.9321641
3  0.9631743 0.8501509 0.9858168 1.0116009 0.9783261 1.0851893 0.9783261 1.0750024 0.9932518 0.9745596
4  1.0116009 0.8960880 1.0473190 1.0952734 1.0612565 1.2325603 1.1786550 1.2781522 1.1378330 1.1505720
5  1.1755733 1.0818052 1.1999648 1.1908876 1.1999648 1.3635374 1.3350011 1.3912819 1.2612979 1.2837078
6  1.3217558 1.1786550 1.3083328 1.3812818 1.3558352 1.4973884 1.5260563 1.5892352 1.4350845 1.4350845
7  1.4816045 1.3862944 1.5475625 1.6292405 1.5892352 1.7404662 1.3609766 1.4350845 1.6292405 1.6094379
8  1.6677068 1.5260563 1.7749524 1.7047481 1.6863990 1.9021075 1.9169226 2.0014800 1.7917595 1.7578579
9  1.8245493 1.7404662 1.8562980 1.9021075 1.8405496 2.0541237 2.0281482 2.1517622 1.8870696 1.8718022
10 1.9459101 1.7917595 1.9600948 2.0014800 1.9740810 2.1282317 2.1400662 2.2407097 1.9600948 1.9459101
11 2.3466020 2.1758874 2.3617970 2.2995806 2.3693087 2.5176965 2.5937611 2.6609586 2.3887628 2.3005831
12 2.3542283 2.2038691 2.3194422 2.4132316 2.3832430 2.4923787 2.6144719 2.6433339 2.4105422 2.4069451
13 2.4630018 2.3292270 2.4890647 2.5071573 2.4874035 2.6354795 2.7146947 2.7504709 2.5233258 2.5087859
14 2.5257286 2.4024304 2.5603233 2.5832426 2.5771819 2.7047113 2.7725887 2.8320362 2.5764218 2.5556757
15 2.5641798 2.4587338 2.6232183 2.6173958 2.6078615 2.7160184 2.7440606 2.8172035 2.5400259 2.5376572
16 2.5368664 2.3988040 2.5877640 2.5006159 2.5580022 2.7013612 2.7788193 2.8507065 2.5572273 2.5922652
17 2.6347624 2.5455313 2.6525375 2.6858046 2.6851227 2.7856283 2.8746939 2.8986706 2.6525375 2.6623552
18 2.7140323 2.5603233 2.7382560 2.7337179 2.7304638 2.8343891 2.9365129 2.9699015 2.7479117 2.7825391
         Nov       Dec
1  0.7561220 0.8241754
2  0.8628900 0.9321641
3  0.9001613 0.9516579
4  1.0508216 1.1693814
5  1.1693814 1.3001917
6  1.3350011 1.5040774
7  1.5475625 1.7047481
8  1.7047481 1.8562980
9  1.7917595 2.0281482
10 1.8870696 2.0794415
11 2.2192035 2.3924258
12 2.3025851 2.4832386
13 2.4440847 2.5710843
14 2.4840730 2.5748997
15 2.4141265 2.5855058
16 2.5063419 2.6340448
17 2.5641798 2.7206373
18 2.6973262 2.8355635
```

Data plot:

[image]

The intervention analysis procedure allowed me to subtract a series of interventions from this data, and then the data transformed from the green to black line in the following plot:

[image]

The interventions can be seen here:

```
types  t
TC     79
LC     121
TC     81
AO     14
AO     87
AO     124
AO     184
TC     31
LC     130
```

Right now, I have the new transformed series and the interventions which I subtracted.

At this point, does it make sense to forecast with ARIMA on the transformed series, then extend the interventions into the forecast period, and sum the two together? (I'm unsure how to get confidence intervals in this case)

Or would it be better to input the intervention types and locations into a transfer function model with the original series? (I think a transfer function ARIMA would spit out confidence intervals automatically in this case)

EDIT:

This is what the predictions look like when I extend the interventions out past the forecasting period, then I make a prediction on the unperturbed process, and add the extended interventions back to the prediction.

Wondering what the proper way to do this is, because this feels like a hack. Black is unperturbed series, green is the result of adding the extended interventions to the forecast.

[image]